# Creating a minfied version of code without react bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-performance

i am having a website written in vanilla js. to integrate react,i added the production links of react and react-dom inside the script tags and **cached at the client**.

https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js

https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js

now when i am building my react project it automatically bundles react and react-dom which is not required **(duplicate dependency)**. how can i build the react project without react and react-dom bundle?